# How to use multiple threads in Java to iterate over a Collection where no two threads ever iterate over the same part of the Collection?

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, iteration

I need to iterate over a large `ArrayList` (~50,000 entries) and I need to use multiple threads to do this fairly quickly.

But I need each thread to start at a unique index so that no two threads ever iterate over the same part of the list. There will be a `batchSize` of `100` so each thread will loop from its `startIndex` to `startIndex + 100`.

Is there any way to achieve this? Note that I am only performing read operations here, no writes. Each entry in the list is just a String which is actually an SQL query which I am then executing against a DB via JDBC.

Comment: What type of collection do you use?

Comment: Can you use java 8 `.stream().parallel()`?

Comment: you could split them before and pass the sublists to the workerThreads which do the DB calls

Comment: From previous answer "On second thoughts maybe you can use a ForkJoinPool and fork multiple threads each going through a batch of 100 and join the results of the threads." FWIW :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only intend to read the `List`, not mutate it, you can simply define your `Runnable` to take the `List` and a `startIndex` as constructor arguments.  There's no danger to concurrently reading an `ArrayList` (even the same indices) as long as no threads modify it at the same time.

To be safe, be sure to wrap your `ArrayList` in a call to [`Collections.unmodifiableList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-) and pass *that* `List` to your `Runnable`s.  That way you can be confident the threads will not modify the backing `ArrayList`.

Alternatively, you can construct sublists in your main thread (with [`List.subList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-)) so that you don't need to pass the `startIndex` to each thread.  However you still want to make the sublists unmodifiable before you do so.  Six of one, half a dozen of the other.

Even better would be to use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)'s [`ImmutableList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html); it's naturally thread-safe.

There's also [parallel streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html) in Java 8, but take care with this solution; they're powerful, but easy to get wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Java 8, look at `list.stream().parallel()`

For Java 7, use `subList()` outside of the threads to split the work into pieces. The threads should then just operate on such a sub-list. For most lists, `subList()` is a very efficient operation which doesn't copy the data. If the backing list is modified, then you get a `ConcurrentModificationException`

As the pumping the data to the threads, I suggest to look at the `Executor` API and `Queue`s. Just put all the work pieces in the queue and let the executor figure everything out.

Answer (score 0):

Have an atomic variable:

```
int nextBatch = 0;
```

Increment it every time a thread concumes a new batch:

```
public synchronized int getNextBatch() {
    nextBatch += batchSize;
    if(nextBatch >= arraylist.size()) {
        // The end was reached
        return -1;
    }
    return nextBatch;
}
```

A thread will call this method and get the the range we will need to work on:

```
int start = getNextBatch();
if(start == -1) {
    // The end was reached
}
int end = Math.min(start + batchSize, arraylist.size);

// Iterate over its own range
for(int i = start; i < end; i++) {
    Object obj = arraylist.get(i);
    // Do something with obj
}
```